# Add comboBox at Kendo

Tags: java, jsp, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have Kendo code:

```
<kendo:grid-columns>                                          
        <kendo:grid-column width="auto" title="<label style='color:white;'>Code</label>" field="code"/>
        <kendo:grid-column width="auto" title="<label style='color:white;'>Category</label>" field="Category"/>
        <kendo:grid-column width="auto" title="<label style='color:white;'>Sub Category</label>" field="SubCategory"/>
        <kendo:grid-column width="auto" title="<label style='color:white;'>Description</label>" field="desc"/>
        <kendo:grid-column width="auto" title="<label style='color:white;'>Value</label>" field="budget" template="#=kendo.toString(budget,'n0')#"/>                

            <kendo:grid-column title="&nbsp;" width="175px">
                 <kendo:grid-column-command> 
                    <kendo:grid-column-commandItem name="edit"/> 
                       <kendo:grid-column-commandItem name="delete"/>    
                            </kendo:grid-column-command> 
                         </kendo:grid-column>
```

`Code,Category, Sub Category` input value is `textfield`, and value is `numericupdown`. How to change `Category` and `Sub Category` to `comboBox` ?

I have try learn this [Overview Kendo UI ComboBox](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/combobox/overview#see-also). but that is different case, when I used kendoGrid, I really don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are java if you tagged it correctly using jsp.

> I have try learn this Overview Kendo UI ComboBox. but that is different case, when I used kendoGrid, I really don't understand.

If so you are looking at a wrong place on documentation.

Now to rephrase your question you are looking to have a editor during insert/Edit to have drop down for a certain column.

Specify a custom editing UI for the column. Use the container parameter to create the editing UI.

```
 <kendo:grid-column title="Category" field="category" editor="categoryDropDownEditor" template="#=category.categoryName#"width="180px"/>
```

Here is the javascript method

```
 <script>
    function categoryDropDownEditor(container, options) {
        $('<input data-text-field="categoryName" data-value-field="categoryId" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList({
            autoBind: false,
            dataSource: {                
                transport: {
                    read: "${categoriesUrl}"
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**Make sure you clear your basics concepts by spending time on reading documentation**

- Check this documentation that describe column type. [Editor java.lang.String](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/jsp/grid/column#editor-javalangstring)
- [Live working demo](http://demos.telerik.com/jsp-ui/grid/editing-custom)